# Convert date column to dates excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, csv, date

I am copying values from a CSV file into my xlsm file. In one of the columns is data and time, but excel is not recognizing all of the values in this column as a date because the values are formatted as **dd/mm/yyyy h:mm AM/PM**.

Excel is recognizing some of the values as a date when the month number is below 12. Here is what I have and what I want:

[image]  ----->  [image]
The rows that are left justified in the first image are not being recognized as dates

I tried the following, but it only formats the values that are already set as a date:

```
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    For Each dataColumn In lo.ListColumns
        If InStr(dataColumn.Name, "Date") > 0 Then
            dataColumn.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"
        End If
    Next dataColumn
```

Comment: Which column of your CSV file contains the date you need to process?

Comment: I do not ask that for the sake of asking... I would suggest you to open the csv file as text, formatting that specific column as text (manually or in code), then processing the column in discussion in order to extract `DateSerial` after splitting it on the date separator. Apropos, what separator does your csv file use? You cannot change the format of a cell being interpreted like not date...

Comment: Do you manually copy the date from csv? How do you make that? Is the csv open in Excel? If yes, don't the date look already strange?

Comment: People run into this problem with CSV dates when the date format in the CSV document differs from the Windows Regional Settings in the destination computer. Avoid these problems by properly **importing** the data, which will allow you to designate the proper date format (of the source document), **BEFORE** excel messes things up for you.  Lots of similar questions throughout this forum.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Thanks for pointing that out... had a bit of a brain fart and didn't think of that. Just changed the date format on the system I was extracting the CSV from and we are all good.

Comment: Most who report the problem don't have control over the output format of the CSV involved. Fortunate that you do.  Although an import method might still be useful if there is any chance that the file may be used on a computer with different Windows Regional Settings.